# Androud Studio can't find the JDK after i defined the JAVA_HOME variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, environment-variables

After I installed Android Studio, I had the well-known problem of "No JVM installation found, please install a 64-bit JDK. If you already have a JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables."

So I did what people on the web told me to do, and defined a new Environment Variable JAVA_HOME who had the path of the JDK (I also defined a JDK_HOME variable, since I saw on some places on the web that this  will fix the problem):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwLUz.png] (ignore the language).

But then when I started up Android Studio, the problem still occurred. So I kept looking on the web for solution, and found someone who offered to change the "studio.bat" file in the bin folder. So when I looked for the folder on my computer, it was missing:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7id4E.png]

So I have no clue what might be the problem, and of course not how to fix it. So if any of you can help me, I would be thankful.

Comment: Have you restarted your AS or your computer?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, and re-installed the AS, and the JDK.

Comment: @OrNevo declare the variable in system variables section

Comment: @mangusta is right, the variables mst be declared on system variable not on user variables